# SFDX force:limits:api:display Shows Incorrect / Misleading Values

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, limits, bug

Today 2021-02-20, 14:30 local time, `force:limits:api:display` shows:

```
Package2VersionCreates                       6          6
Package2VersionCreatesWithoutValidation      500        500
```

At the same hour, when trying to create a package version, I get the error:

```
The package2 version create request failed because this organization has reached its daily limit
```

And in fact, `sfdx force:package:version:create:list` shows that the limit is reached, at least when assuming that failed version creation requests count towards the limit:

```
08c09000000oMSWAA2  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-19 13:50
08c09000000oMSgAAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-19 16:48
08c09000000oMSlAAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-19 17:31
08c09000000oMSqAAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-19 17:36
08c09000000oMSvAAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-20 13:29
08c09000000oMT0AAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-20 13:41
08c09000000oMT5AAM  Error    0Ho09000000oLuFCAU     2021-02-20 13:53
```

It would be nice if `force:limits:api:display` took the failed version creation attempts into account, same as the package version creation does when checking / enforcing the limit.

I guess I have to go for a walk until at least 5 o'clock. :-)

Comment: The limits command only reports what the API returns. Have you tried checking the limits in an alternative tool, such as Workbench? If there's a discrepancy, then there's an sfdx problem, if not, there's a problem elsewhere with the API.

Comment: Go to https://workbench.developerforce.com/, log in to the Dev Hub, click on Rest Explorer in the right-most menu, and use the URL /services/data/v50.0/limits. What does that report?

Comment: @sfdcfox: the workbench says the same thing as the force:limits:api:display. But **note**: all I'm saying is that the failed creation attempts should decrease the Remaining count in `force:limits:api:display` if the `force:package:version:create`counts them against the limit it enforces.

Comment: Failed creations should not be counted against you, unless something's changed recently. Are you sure you're authorized to the correct org?

Comment: when I run `force:limits:api:display -u devHub` I see now 2 remaining, which tallies with the output of `force:package:create:list -v devHub`(the -v devHub seems to be implicit in VS Code project setting I am in). Both together confirm that failed version creations (exclusive of the ones failed because of exceeded limits) do count against the limit (which makes sense, the limit being meant to limit the workload that can be generated  in the cloud infrastructure)

Answer (score 2):

The results of `force:limits:api:display` and `force:package:version:create:list` are in agreement when authorizing to the correct org, which in both cases is your Dev Hub org. To make sure you get correct results (assuming the alias for the Dev Hub org is devHub), use:

- `force:limits:api:display -u devHub` for the limits and remaining executions, and
- `force:package:version:create:list -v devHub` for the details.

And yes, failed package version create attempts are counted when enforcing the limit of 6 per 24 hours.